# why in the systemout.log of websphere i see wrong operating system information?

Tags: websphere, was

This is the start of my SystemOut.log of my WAS. Why i see a wrong operating system? i have windows server 2012 and not win srv 2008. Do you know where websphere take this information?

************ Start Display Current Environment ************
-WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.0 [ND 8.5.5.0 gm1319.01] running with process name blabla\blabla\server1 and process id 1234

-Host Operating System is **Windows Server 2008, version 6.2 build 9200**

-Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM

-was.install.root = C:\Program Files\IBM\WASND85

-user.install.root = C:\Program Files\IBM\WASND85\profiles\AppSrv01

-Java Home = C:\Program Files\IBM\WASND85\java\jre
-ws.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\IBM\WASND85/java/lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\WAS

-Classpath = C:\Program Files\IBM\WASND85\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\Pro

-Java Library path = C:\Program Files\IBM\WASND85/lib/native/win/x86_64/;C:\P

-Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb626-20130112.01

************* End Display Current Environment *************

Thankyou in advance!!!!!!
bye

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, WAS is taking the information from system property "os.name" and "os.version".

A quick way of checking is to write a quick java test class and have it print out the result of System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase() and  System.getProperty("version").toLowerCase(). Then verify if they match the string you got from WAS log files' header.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM pulls this information from a Windows API call (GetVersionEx). There was a change to this Windows API that required a change to the JDK in order to show the correct Windows OS name:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059803

Since you are running a very old version of Java, upgrading to a later version should help.